# Cloudfront - Propagation of files across CDN?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, uploading, amazon-cloudfront

got a situation where I'm uploading files to S3 for a AWS Cloudfront distro. As soon as they're uploaded and perms set I'm sending my user to view the content... but I've just had a situation where the content failed to materialise for some 3 minutes or so.

I presume this is a high traffic period of such for AWS and files took a while to propagate round the network?

Is there any feedback protocols anyone knows of to check for this (other than generic tries on file downloading) or if this is the case, or another explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files don't propagate around CloudFront, each CloudFront location fetches data from the origin server individually as-needed. If you don't get any requests from Asia, the Asian CloudFront servers will never fetch the files.

Comment: But, then I can't understand why the files didn't download? The files were accessible via S3 directly, so why the delay?